# To extract value from a listbox using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
      <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-fullWidth" data-testid="timezone-input">
          <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl">
             <div class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSelect" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox">Europe/London</div>
               <input type="hidden" value="Europe/London">
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"><path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path></svg></div></div>
```

How do I extract the value from the listbox using cypress? I used the following code

```
cy.get('[data-testid="timezone-input"] div div').invoke("val").should("eq", "Europe/London");
```

but i get `CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected '' to equal 'Europe/London`

Comment: Please indent your HTML, it's hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to check the content of the `div` or of the `input`, but I'd try either one of these.

For the `div`:

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="timezone-input"] div div').contains('Europe/London');
```

For the `input`:

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="timezone-input"] input').should('have.value', 'Europe/London');
```

Comment: Thanks guillaume.deslandes for the answer. I want to extract the current time.zone value say 'europe/london' and verify whether the same timezone settings is reflected in another page. I used the following code  
   `this.timevalue = cy.get('[data-testid="timezone-input"] input');
    assert.equals(this.timevalue, "Europe/London", "equals");`. I get `TypeError: assert.equals is not a function`

Comment: Did you try my second command? You cannot store Cypress `get` result directly, it returns a Promise-like object that they use to chain commands. Have a look at their doc https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Variables

Comment: Yes I am trying your second command to change the value from 'Europe/London' to 'GMT' using `cy.get(TIME_ZONE_INPUT).type("GMT");` but i get the CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.type() failed because this element is not visible:

<input type="hidden" value="Europe/London">

This element '<input>' is not visible because it has CSS property: 'display: none'

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MUI, but if the input is hidden, there should be a better target for Cypress `type` command. Try to inspect your page to know what is usable. Or you could try to `force` the typing with `cy.get(TIME_ZONE_INPUT).type("GMT", { force: true });` but this should be a last resort... You can use the selector playground in Cypress GUI (the target icon, left side of address bar).

Comment: Thanks guillaume.deslandes for your response. The below code helped `cy.get('[data-testid="timezone-input"] div div')
      .click()
      .get('[data-value="GMT"]')
      .click();`